# Full Join on multiple tables (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

In postgresql I got 4 tables

```
 Table A:
 ----------- 
 a_id 
 a_date

 Table B 
 -----------
 a_id b_id

 Table C: 
 -------------------
 c_id 
 b_id 
 invoice_number

 Table D
 -------------------
 d_id 
 invoice_number 
 value_D
```

Multiple records have value_D

I would like to select Table A, Table B, Table C and Table D, where a_date BETWEEN X AND Y.
However, I would also like to select all the other value_D that are not included in my selection (so A innerjoin B innerjoin C full outerjoin D)

**my code**

```
SELECT 
   Table A, Table B, Table C, Table D
FROM 
   Table A
JOIN
   Table B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
JOIN
   Table C ON B.b_id = C.b_id
FULL OUTER JOIN
   Table D ON C.invoice_number = D.invoice_number
WHERE
   A.a_date BETWEEN X AND Y;
```

It only shows D.value_d for the A.a_id, where A.a_date BETWEEN X and Y.
I would like however that D.value_d would also be shown for A.a_id, where A.a_date is also other.

I am kinda a newbie, so hopefully it is understandable and you could help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're specifically telling it to restrict the A rows to those where A,a_date BETWEEN X AND Y in the where clause, so that's what you're getting. You're going to have to express what you want a little better - especially to yourself I suspect.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause acts on the *result* of the `JOIN` clauses, i.e. it is executed "after" everything else. So regardless of what kind of `JOIN`s you use, you will only see rows matching your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Perhaps you could include an example of the current output, and the desired output, for some example input? At the moment it's a bit unclear which values of `D.value_d` you expect/want to see.

Comment: I think I solved it. I know it was confusing the way is stated it. I think the solution code makes it more understanding.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also add more conditions to the Where clause, for example:
"a_date BETWEEN X AND Y OR a_date > '2015-04-21'". This will retrieve the union of both conditions.

Regards

Comment: @ Marcos, yes i see. But instead to add other date. I would like to add:

...
OR value_D = {the previous selected value_D}

However I have no clue how I can select certain records with a certain value (value_D) under a certain condition (the date in my situation) and then select other records as well under the condition of the value selected before (value_D).

I hope I haven't stated it to confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you need but if what you are looking for is to add more results (value_D) that do not satisfy the between clause you can use and "union" query.
select value_D
from ......
where a_date BETWEEN X AND
union
select value_D
from ...
where value_D not a_date BETWEEN X AND value_D = X

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.

```
SELECT Table A, Table B, Table C, Table D 
FROM Table A
JOIN Table B ON A.a_id = B.a_id
JOIN Table C ON B.b_id = C.b_id
JOIN Table D ON C.invoice_number = D.invoice_number
WHERE A.a_date BETWEEN X AND Y OR
D.value_D IN (SELECT D.value_D
             FROM Table D
             JOIN Table C ON D.invoice_number on C.invoice_number
             JOIN Table B ON C.b_id = B.b_id
             JOIN Table A ON B.a_id = A.a_id
             WHERE A.a_date BETWEEN X AND Y);
```

Thank you all for the help guys!